# Calculus 2 - line equations and vectors

Tags: calculus

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9f44.png)

I dont know how line equation can be written as vectors, so that I do not understand how to show this

Question:

Show that $ l_{t,\omega}$ is given parametrically as the set of points

$l_{t,\omega} $= {t$\omega$ + s $\hat{\omega}$| s $\in (-\infty,\infty)$}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.